# Как вывести один пост по другому WP?

Tags: wordpress

В категории очень много постов(записей) и много из них только с заглавиями , а много с содержанием и тд , но вот надо , чтоб один пост именно вот который мне нужен , выводом отличался от других.
П.С. вывод по id типа ('1') не подойдет , так как этот пост может быть и другого id. Можно ли как то посту присвоить что ли права какие нибудь или тип этого указав , что он ну там главный или тип этого ?

```
$posts = get_posts(array('cat'=>$category->term_id, 
'post_type' => 'post', 
'meta_query' => array( 
 array( 
  'key' => '****', // название поля Истина/Лож
  'value' => '1', //если ИСТИНА что эта страница главная 
  'compare' => '=', 
  ), 
), 
));
```

у меня такая идея , но не знаю будет ли работать или нет ....

Comment: может быть подойдёт проверка по заголовку записи с помощью `get_page_by_title`

Comment: Обновил вопрос , посмотрите , пожалуйста. 
p.s. проверка на заголовок не пойдет

Comment: В WordPress из коробки есть "Прилепленные записи" (Sticky Posts). Или добавить метаполе к нужным постам, типа `is_general` и в лупе цепляться за него (или юзать хук `pre_get_posts`)  и ставить нужные классы или какая там у вас задача. Про стики есть у Миши - https://misha.blog/wordpress/sticky-posts.html

Comment: Что такое "по другому WP"?

Answer (score 0):

> но вот надо , чтоб один пост именно вот который мне нужен , выводом
>   отличался от других.

Можно создать [шаблон поста](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/#creating-page-templates-for-specific-post-types) и выбирать его.

Comment: думал об этом , но это не вариант

Comment: И почему же? Нормально опиши задачу.

Comment: есть к примеру 5 постов и один из них , который админ выберет , надо вывести наверху страницы с другим оформлением , все остальные запись уже под низом выводим с другим оформление

Comment: Блин, научись тогда задавать вопросы... **mihdan** угадал и вчера в комментах всё рассказал

Comment: я по его способу и сделал сегодня. Но просто сперва хотелось свою ошибку исправить , но ладно .